# Generic c# casting

Tags: c#, .net, generics

```
interface ISample
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
public class MyClass : ISample
{
    public int Id
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The above is a class which implements a interface ISample. Using generics i have added the below method to convert an object of given type to another type .

```
private TResult Sample<TSource, TResult>(TSource source)
            where TSource : TResult
{
   return (TResult)(source);
}
```

using Generics how do i achieve the reverse of the same that is given an ISample object i want to convert it back to MyClass object where ISample is the TSource and TResult is MyClass where TResult implements TSource.

Comment: You can´t do this because when you have an instance of `ISample`, who guarantees that it´s actually an instance of `MyClass` and not of any other one implementing that interface? Anyway why do you even have this method? What does it do what a simple `(ISample) myInstanceOfMyClass` won´t do for you?

Comment: If `TSource` inherits from `TResult` (which is what you've set up there), then any object of type `TSource` can already implicitly be cast down to a `TResult`. However, I do think that if you invert it (`TResult` inherits from `TSource`), that you can _somewhat_ guarantee that a conversion is possible; or at least you'll run into a compiler error instead of a runtime exception.

Answer (score 1):

You would simply have to switch from

```
where TSource : TResult
```

to

```
where TResult : TSource
```

ending up with code that might look like

```
private TResult ToInterface<TSource, TResult>(TSource source) where TSource : TResult
{
    return source;
}

private TResult FromInterface<TSource, TResult>(TSource source) where TResult : TSource
{
    return source as TResult;
}
```

Be aware that the FromInterface function will throw an InvalidCastException if the 'source' parameter is not of type TResult or does not inherit from TResult.

---

**Edit:**

See the answer by Lajos Arpad.

Comment: You could use the cast `as` to avoid the exception and let the user of the function chose how to deal with the invalid cast instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: That's true, but the question was about creating a generic solution for casting between types in a hierarchy, not about handling invalid casts. I agree that it is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will not know in advance that you intend to do downcasting from `TSource` to `TResult`. You will need to cast your `TSource` instance into something that is surely a superclass of `TResult`, so you will need to cast `TSource` to `object` first:

```
(TResult)((object)source)
```

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comment section by @Zdeněk Jelínek, Eric Lippert has written a blog [post about](https://ericlippert.com/2015/10/14/casts-and-type-parameters-do-not-mix/) this.

Comment: Your solution is correct. Eric Lippert has blogged about this with more extensive explanation: https://ericlippert.com/2015/10/14/casts-and-type-parameters-do-not-mix/

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek thank you for your input, I have added these valuable details to the answer.